# Laravel Query Builder : Where pivot not in

Tags: sql, laravel, pivot

`wherePivotIn` is mentionend [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (under *Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns*) but I can't find anything about the opposite function.

As the `wherePivotIn` already exists but not the `wherePivotNOTIn`, I edited this file : `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquant/Relations/BelongsToMany.php`

And added this function

```
public function wherePivotNotIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
    {
        $this->pivotWhereIns[] = func_get_args();

        return $this->whereNotIn($this->table.'.'.$column, $values, $boolean, $not);
    }
```

Now the `wherePivotNotIn` exist and is working. But my question is:

Is it safe to update this file?
In case of update, I guess I will lose this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After dinging a bit, I found out that the `whereIn` method accept more than 2 arguments.

We juste have to use it like that to use a "wherePivot**Not**In"

```
->wherePivotIn($column,$value,'and','NotIn')
```

No need to declare a new class or using scope!

Comment: In new versions the value `NotIn` just be a Truthy value meaning it can be 'true` or any other value that evaluates to `true`  so it can be rewritten as. `->wherePivotIn($column,$value,'and', true)`

Answer (score 0):

Never edit what is inside the vendor directory. Create your own method to meet your need, in case it does not exist.

In your case, you can define a [Local Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes)

It will look like:

```
class Task extends Model
{

    public function scopeWherePivotNotIn($query)
    {
         /**/            
    }

}

$tasks = Task::wherePivotNotIn()->get();
```

Comment: Where should I create this new class and how to use it by default instead of the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah don't update vendor files that's a no no. Instead , create a class that extends `BelongsToMany` and put your implementation in there. You'll lose your changes as soon as the file updates.