# Laravel where pivot

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a subscription system. Every subscription has a type, and every `subscription_type` has articles. When a subscription is created the
`articles` from that `subscription type` where the size is `M` should be created in the `subscription_articles` table.

I've got this table structure:

```
subscription
- id
- name
- subscription_type_id

subscription_type
- id
- name

article
- id
- name
- price

subscription_articles
- id
- subscription_id
- article_id

subscription_type_articles
- id
- subscription_type_id
- article_id
- size
```

Relations are like this:

**subscription** model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubscriptionType::class, 'subscription_type_id');
}
```

**subscription type** model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'subscription_type_articles');
}
```

When a `subscription` is created the `articles` that are coupled in `subscription_type_articles` where the size is `M` should be created in 
the `subscription_articles` table.

I try that like this:

```
$articles = $subscription->type->articles()->wherePivot('size', '=', 'M');
```

I get this error:

> local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 130027520 bytes)

Obviously something is wrong, what could it be?

Comment: It's php - memory_limit error, you need to edit your `php.ini` file. Edit `memory_limit` to your desire value. A simple way to overwrite memory_limit in php code during runtime, try `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` in `articles()` to see if it works

Comment: That's not working.

Comment: Maybe try: `->wherePivot('size', 'M');` - in fact this Allowed memory size exhausted error is related with php configs for memory_limit as I said

Comment: eventhough this is a memory limit error, the solution is not to increase the memory. Its likely some sort of loop that shouldnt be there. I cant judge by the information, but I suggest to install laravel debugbar via composer and try to look at the query tab.

Comment: Could you provide more code? Your controller for instance

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the error is caused by `$articles = $subscription->type->articles()->wherePivot('size', '=', 'M');` ? Do you think you have a very very large number of objects loaded (if you have a really large number of rows in you database) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Query Builder : Where pivot not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519583/laravel-query-builder-where-pivot-not-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I should call `->get();` at the end of the method. So result is:

```
$articles = $subscription->type->articles()->wherePivot('size', '=', 'M')->get();
```